# regex capture text then add another before and after captured

Tags: regex

For the input string:

```
"test.com/dfafsf--fasfgf--fefegf-12345678+test (first text)"
```

I want to apply regex to check if the input string contains: `12345678+test`

if found then want to convert it into this:

```
sample.com/klklklklkl-klklkl-'CAPTURED12345678'+fefgreg-dgferg
```

I have trid this regex:

```
\d+(?=+test)
```

Has anyone an idea?

Comment: your final output doesn't have any relevance with your first text which contains test.com........12345678+test .... if it doesn't have any relevance why bother for any further regex? just put whatever you want before and after your first captured value...

Comment: Rizwan you are right. No relevance after capturing. my question is, how can I add text before and after my captured digits. When I try typing it directly after expression it doesn't work. I know a very basic question probably.

Comment: What language are you using ?

Comment: PCRE (PHP) but any other could also apply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your **pattern** is correct. But if you have your string is a file:
you can use **Perl** to **match** and **substitute** in one step:

for the input:

```
"test.com/dfafsf--fasfgf--fefegf-12345678+test (first text)"
```

you can apply:

```
perl -lpe '/\d+(?=\+test)/g && ($m = $&) && s/^.+$/sample.com\/klklklklkl-klklkl-'CAPTURED'$m+fefgreg-dgferg/g' file
```

1. check if the line has match: `/\d+(?=\+test)/g`
2. then save the result: `($m = $&)`
3. lastly substitution the entire line: `s/^.+$/sample.com\/klklklklkl-klklkl-'CAPTURED'$m+fefgreg-dgferg/g`

And the output is:

```
sample.com/klklklklkl-klklkl-CAPTURED12345678+fefgreg-dgferg
```

And as you can see there is no single `'` quote around **CAPTURED12345678** since I used [teg:bash] and it cannot handle that and for that you use `'"'"'CAPTURED$m'"'"'` instead.

---

But if you want: *my question is, how can I add text before and after my captured digits*

you need to know where is your pattern stored or in fact which **variable** or **method** takes care of the **sub-match**.  For example if **Perl** the `$&` takes care of it and I used this as well. Or in **C++** the `.str()` method of class `match_results`

So with **Perl** you can use `s/^.+$/Before-Match $& After-Match/g`  and if you apply it to the file:

```
perl -lpe '/\d+(?=\+test)/g && ($m = $&) && s/^.+$/Before-Match=> $m <=After-Match/g' file
```

the output will be:

```
Before-Match=> 12345678 <=After-Match
```